# TFS2012 - can't create new team projects using some templates

Tags: tfs

We've just set up a new TFS2012, and somehow creating new team projects have stopped working when using Scrum 2.2 and CMMI 6.2 (the agile template works perfectly).

The TFS is complaining about trying to set a non-NULL-able column to null:

```
---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2013-07-22T15:36:52
Module: Engine
Event Description: TF30162: Task "WITs" from Group "WorkItemTracking" failed
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
Exception Message: There is a problem on the server. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.Execute(ProjectCreationContext ctxt, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.TaskExecutor.PerformTask(IProjectComponentCreator componentCreator, ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.RunTask(Object taskObj)
--   Inner Exception   --
Exception Message: There is a problem on the server. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator. (type UnexpectedErrorException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SendUpdatePackage(XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, Boolean bulk)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Provision.UpdatePackageOptimizer.Update(XmlElement updatePackage)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Provision.UpdatePackageOptimizer.Submit(XmlElement rootElement)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Provision.UpdatePackageOptimizer.Submit(Snapshot snapshot, Int32 projectId, XmlElement updatePackage)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Provision.ProvisionClass.Submit(ActionType action, Snapshot snapshot, Int32 projectId, WITImporter importer)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Provision.ProvisionClass.ImportValidateWorkItemTypeInternal(Int32 projectId, String methodologyName, XmlElement typeElement, ActionType action)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemTypeCollection.Import(String definition, String methodologyName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.WitPcwTask.WorkItemTypesTask.UploadTypeDefinition(String file, Boolean execute)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.WitPcwTask.WorkItemTypesTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.Parse(ContextWrapper wrapper, XmlNode taskXml, Boolean fExecute)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.Execute(ProjectCreationContext ctxt, XmlNode taskXml)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL. (type SoapException)SoapException Details: <detail ExceptionMessage="Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL." BaseExceptionName="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"><details id="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/WorkItemTracking/faultdetail/03" /></detail>
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.RetryHandler.HandleSoapException(SoapException se)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.WorkItemServer.Update(String requestId, XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, MetadataTableHaveEntry[] metadataHave, String& dbStamp, IMetadataRowSets& metadata)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SendUpdatePackage(XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, Boolean bulk)

--- end Exception entry ---
```

To me it looks like the .xml's defining the template have been changed / corrupted or something. But I have no idea where to start, as there seem to be no other out there with similar issues.

I've tried to clear cache as most answers suggests, but with no luck.

I'm totally open for suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the SQL-server did the trick (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c4266b7d-a221-473e-847b-ed6c04d8c03c/tf30162-task-wits-from-group-workitemtracking-failed). What exactly was the issue, I don't know - but it works now.